# Change Retrofit's base use by external config file

Tags: spring-boot, retrofit2

In my spring boot I use Retrofit.

```
public class RestClientFactory {
    static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8091/";
    static final String JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json";


  private static Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(httpClient.build());
```

In interface:

```
@GET("api/v1/hello")
    Call<JsonElement> sayHello();
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But I need the client to can change base url from `http://127.0.0.1:8091/` to any another.

Ideally the it's must be from external config file.
Is it possible it Spring Boot 2.x

Comment: what do you mean by external config file? like application.properties?

Comment: @pero_hero. I need to can change endpoint for external service. Yes this can be file like application.properties or application.yml. Or may be set as param, like this: java -jar my_app.jar -some_param_here=new_ip

Answer (score 1):

you can use a static field for the builder and initialize it first when spring magic has provided you with the value of the base url:

```
private static Retrofit.Builder builder;

@Value("${API_BASE_URL}")
public void createBuilder(String url) {    
    builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(url)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .client(httpClient.build());
}
```

then you can provide a value for it in `application.properties`:

```
API_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8091/
```

and overwrite it with:

```
java -jar my_app.jar ---API_BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```